# Extracting SQL data using regular expression

Tags: java, regex

I have the un proper data in this way. I need to extract the data before dot and after dot symbol using regular expression. I am using  but I am not able to get exact data.

```
String rightHeading=null;
        String leftHeading=null;

String formulaData="ifnull(\"Content Status\".\"Week Of Quarter\",0)";

            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(\"?([^()]*?)\"?)\\.(\"?([@#$%><{}\\w ]*)\"?)").matcher(formulaData);
            while (matcher.find()) 
            {
            String Column_Data=matcher.group(0);
            String[] pieces = Column_Data.split("\\.");
            rightHeading=pieces[0].replace("\"", "");
            leftHeading=pieces[1].replace("\"", "");

             System.out.println(rightHeading+ ": "+leftHeading);
             }//while
```

Output which I got is:

```
   ifnullContent Status.Week Of Quarter,0)
```

Expected output:

```
    Content Status.Week Of Quarter
```

Comment: What is the current output of your regex?

Comment: I edited the code please check

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data and what you would like to be extracted?

Comment: Did Rossiar's assistance help here? If so, please consider upvoting and/or accepting his answer.

Answer (score 1):

Below is my solution for your problem, along with the output that it produces.

```
    String formulaData="(100*(FILTER(\"Fact - Bookings\".\"$ Total Gross Bookings\" USING (\"Booking Date\".\"Year\" =  VALUEOF(\"CUR_YEAR\")))  - FILTER(Fact - Bookings.$ Total Gross BookingsData USING \"Booking Date\".\"Year\" =  VALUEOF(\"PREV_YEAR\") AND  \"Booking Date\".Sortable Number <= VALUEOF(\"PRV_YEAR_TD\") ) ) / FILTER(Fact - Bookings.$TotalGrossBookingsUsage \" USING \"Booking Date\".\"Year\" =  VALUEOF(\"PREV_YEAR\") AND \"Booking Date\".\"Sortable Number\" <= VALUEOF(\"PRV_YEAR_TD\") ) )";

    String p1 = "(\"(\\w*\\s*-*)*?\"\\.\".*?\")|((?:\\()((\\w*\\s*-*)*?\\.\\$\\w+))|(\"(\\w*\\s*-*)*?\"\\.(\\w+\\s+)+)";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(p1);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(formulaData);

    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(0).replaceAll("\"|\\(|\\)", ""));
    }
```

Outputs:

```
Fact - Bookings.$ Total Gross Bookings
Booking Date.Year
Fact - Bookings.$ Total Gross BookingsData
Booking Date.Year
Booking Date.Sortable Number
Fact - Bookings.$TotalGrossBookingsUsage
Booking Date.Year
Booking Date.Sortable Number
```

As you can see, I didn't use actually use a horrifically complex regex to solve your problem. This is because your input is far too varied to use this tool effectively.

The fact that your `table.field` pairs sometimes had `$` or `"` symbols inside them made the data very inconsistent. Regular expressions find it hard to deal with this level of complexity, so I think my solution (in this example) is workable.

However, in future if you have any control over your data input, please try to sanitize it and make it as consistent as possible.

**EDIT**
Since that didn't work out for you, I've gone and changed my code snippet to use a regular expression.

Comment: but for dynamic data we cant use String for splitting. Dynamic data can be in thousands of lines. so if we use regular expression it get the format

Comment: Can you standardise the data at all? It's too difficult to find generic data with spaces, $ and " after a dot, there isn't a clearly defined end point for the regex to finish on.

Comment: See m updated formulaData string , If i use ur code  with that string i am getting that output String formulaData="ifnull(\"Content Status\".\"Week Of Quarter\",0)";

Comment: Yes I understand that my solution isn't working the way you want it to. Where is this data coming from?

Answer (score -1):

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([\\w[\\$#@\\-^&]\\w\\[\\]' $]+)\\.([\\w\\[\\]' $]+)").matcher(formulaData);

while (matcher.lookingAt()) {

                System.out.print("Start index: " + matcher.start());
                System.out.print(" End index: " + matcher.end());
                System.out.println(" Found: " + matcher.group());
            }
```

lookingAt() is more suitable here as per the requirements and as mentioned in doc  --
lookingAt()  Attempts to match the input sequence, starting at the beginning of the region, against the pattern.

Like the matches method, this method always starts at the beginning of the region; unlike that method, it does not require that the entire region be matched.

If the match succeeds then more information can be obtained via the start, end, and group methods.

Hope this helps.